# How to get users list of joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, list, joomla2.5

How to get list of users by id and username?

Comment: Have you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799933/print-all-users-joomla-2-5 ?

Comment: Sorry we can't give our hands :(

Comment: Thank you Rikesh, but i dont want get query, is there any function to get all users. for example i can get current user whit getUser().

Comment: There are no such function available to get all the list of users if you like to get it then you have create your own custom function or a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I found this result from  [Print All Users - Joomla 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799933/print-all-users-joomla-2-5/12800557#12800557)

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__users" ;
$db->setQuery($query);

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo $row->id.'|'.$row->username.'|'.$row->email;
}
```

Comment: you should credit the stackoverflow answer you copied your _answer_ from http://stackoverflow.com/a/12800557/2219831